# How theming off-line page?

Tags: 7, theming, maintenance-mode

I read [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_maintenance_page/7) and put files theme folder.

`maintenance-page.tpl.php` works well,

but `maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php` don't work.

How theming off-line page ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your database server was offline when you tested ? The API description says

> "maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php" can be used when the database is offline to hide errors and completely replace the content.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I see `Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error message
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) in lock_may_be_available() (line 164 of xxx\includes\lock.inc).'

Comment: I see, it could be a bug then I don't have time to reproduce it now. Please file an issue here http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal?title=Documentation%20problem%20with%20template_preprocess_maintenance_page&component=documentation&categories=bug&version=156281&body=API%20page%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Fdrupal%2Fincludes--theme.inc%2Ffunction%2Ftemplate_preprocess_maintenance_page%2F7%0A%0ADescribe%20the%20problem%20you%20have%20found%3A%0A